# automapper Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to map the following entities:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public List<Telephone> Telephones { get; set; }
}

public class SearchPersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string LicencePlate { get; set; }
    public string CarMake { get; set; }
    public string CarModel { get; set; }
}
```

I do that:

```
  AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<List<SearchPersonViewModel>, List<Person>>();
 List<SearchPersonViewModel> model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Person>, List<SearchPersonViewModel>>(persons);
```

And I get the exception 'Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.'

I don't see what's wrong with my code, anyone could help ?

Comment: You should validate your mappings as detailed [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation). You don't have a mapping defined for `Person` -> `SearchPersonViewModel`, and you are missing mapping definitions for your properties (eg, DOB, Telephones, etc).